# What is changing my Windows Firewall rules?

Tags: windows-8.1, firewall, windows-firewall

I have pretty much explicitly blocked everything in my Windows 8.1 outgoing Windows firewall rules, but the following rules are always enabled again after I restart: ICMPv4-Out, ICMPv6-Out, LLMNR-UDP-Out, NB-Datagram-Out, NB-Name-Out, NB-Session-Out, and finally SMB-Out.

As far as I can tell my system don't use any of these services and I would like to always block it, but how can I achieve this when these services are always allowed by default after a reboot?

**Update**

I figured out that setting the *block* action rather than just disabling the rule seems to fix the problem. But I would still like to know what is trying to enable these rules and why.

Comment: Are you on a domain?

Comment: No, I'm conncted to a guest or public network now.